# C# drawing Graph, interface

Tags: c#, graph, interface, xna

I'm writing application for generating huge graphs and displaying them. First i'v try WPF with sharpGL but performance was horrible. Then i tried XNA and it was better. But there i have lack of interface. I can try use XNA in WinForms maybe, but it costs performance. For now it's my only option. 
So i'v tried draw graph on XNA. For now, i approach this by primitives drawing, but i'm not quite satisfied with performance. I'm drawing two graphs on scene.
First have 10k vertices and about 30k edges, second have 20k vertices and 30k edges.I'm drawing edges like this:

```
    GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(PrimitiveType.LineList, verticesDelanuay, 0, Graph.DelaunayEdges.Count);
    GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(PrimitiveType.LineList, verticesVoronoi, 0, Graph.VoronoiEdges.Count);
```

but for every vertex i want to draw some kind of square. For now, i'm drawing four triangles for every vertex. Like this:

```
graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices, 0, vertices.Length, indices, 0, (int)CircleStep, VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration);
```

For all this drawing i want to have camera, which can zoom in, out and move. I did this, by basicEffect.View and passing proper Matrix.

For those data i have 10 - 15 fps. Is it a normal performance or can i do something to speed things up?

I want to know what is the fastest way for draw something like this and is it a better way to have interface and graphical environment in one than WinForm + XNA?

Comment: To see what you can speed up, we need more code!

Comment: Does it help using Vertex- and IndexBuffers?

Comment: You should really run a profiler to see where the performance bottlenecks are.